# Couldn't find libtensorflow_demo.so while importing Tensorflow example on Android

Tags: android, tensorflow

I am importing Tensorflow example to run it in Android 5 simulator on Windows, but I am getting this error. Do you know why that happens?

> 05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): Process:
>   org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 1189 05-25 17:14:31.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1189): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/org.tensorflow.demo-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtensorflow_demo.so" 05-25
>   17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366) 05-25 17:14:31.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989) 05-25 17:14:31.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   org.tensorflow.demo.TensorflowClassifier.(TensorflowClassifier.java:47)
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   org.tensorflow.demo.TensorflowImageListener.(TensorflowImageListener.java:55)
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.(CameraConnectionFragment.java:452)
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   org.tensorflow.demo.CameraConnectionFragment.newInstance(CameraConnectionFragment.java:271)
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:33)
>   05-25 17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) 05-25
>   17:14:31.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)

Below my AVD settings --

[image]

Comment: Did you download the pre-built windows artifacts? Did you put the assets in the correct place (see "install model files" in the [demo page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android))